# remove focus from TextField JavaFX

Tags: javafx, focus

I can not remove focus from the `TextField`. On my view I only have one editable content: Text in a `TextField`. The problem is that as a user one never gets rid of the focus (because there is nothing else to focus on), once the `TextField` is focused. I want to remove the focus from the `TextField`.

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
public class ControllerMain implements Initializable {
    private MainApp app;
    private ObservableList<UserData> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    @FXML
    private Button btnAdd;
    @FXML
    public TableView<UserData> table = new TableView<>();
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<UserData, String> column1;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<UserData, Integer> column2;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<UserData, String> column3;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<UserData, String> column4;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<UserData, Integer> column5;
    @FXML
    private TextField txtSearch;

    public ControllerMain() {
    }

    public void setApp(MainApp instance) {
        this.app = instance;
    }


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        String companyName = "companyName";
        column1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>(companyName));
        String phone = "phone";
        column2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>(phone));
        String address = "address";
        column3.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>(address));
        String other = "other";
        column4.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>(other));
        String id = "id";
        column5.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>(id));
        column5.setVisible(false);
        initSearchFilter();
    }

    private void initSearchFilter() {
        txtSearch.textProperty().addListener(o -> {
            if (txtSearch.textProperty().get().isEmpty()) {
                table.setItems(data);
                return;
            }
            ObservableList<UserData> tableItems = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            ObservableList<TableColumn<UserData, ?>> cols = table.getColumns();
            for (UserData aData : data) {
                for (TableColumn<UserData, ?> col1 : cols) {
                    String cellValue = col1.getCellData(aData).toString();
                    cellValue = cellValue.toLowerCase();
                    if (cellValue.contains(txtSearch.textProperty().get().toLowerCase())) {
                        tableItems.add(aData);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            table.setItems(tableItems);
        });
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleOpenAddForm() throws IOException {
        UserData userData = new UserData();
        app.initAddForm();
        getData().add(userData);
        loadDatabaseData();
    }

    @FXML
    private void deleteHandle() {
        try (Connection con = new DBConnect().getConnected();
             PreparedStatement prep = con.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM job.job WHERE job.id = ?")) {
            UserData selectedItem = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            prep.setInt(1, selectedItem.getId());
            prep.execute();
            getData().remove(selectedItem);
            loadDatabaseData();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Ошибка удаления: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleOpenUpdateForm() throws IOException {
        UserData userData = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        app.initUpdateForm(userData);
        userData.setId(userData.idProperty().getValue());
        userData.setCompanyName(userData.companyNameProperty().getValue());
        userData.setPhone(userData.phoneProperty().getValue());
        userData.setAddress(userData.addressProperty().getValue());
        userData.setOther(userData.otherProperty().getValue());
        loadDatabaseData();
    }

    public void loadDatabaseData() {
        try (Connection con = new DBConnect().getConnected();
             PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT  * FROM job.job");
             ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery()) {
            getData().clear();
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                getData().add(new UserData(
                        resultSet.getInt("id"),
                        resultSet.getString("company_name"),
                        resultSet.getInt("phone"),
                        resultSet.getString("address"),
                        resultSet.getString("other")
                ));
                table.setItems(getData());
            }

            txtSearch.setFocusTraversable(false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error on Building Data");
        }
    }

    private ObservableList<UserData> getData() {
        return data;
    }


}
```

FXML

```xml
<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0"
        prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
        fx:controller="com.mysoft.controller.ControllerMain">
 <center>
        <TableView fx:id="table" prefHeight="370.0" prefWidth="613.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER"
                   focusTraversable="false">
            <columns>
                <TableColumn fx:id="column1" prefWidth="139.0" text="Название компании"/>
                <TableColumn fx:id="column2" minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="85.0" text="Телефон"/>
                <TableColumn fx:id="column3" minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="217.0" text="Адрес"/>
                <TableColumn fx:id="column4" minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="156.0" text="Другое"/>
                <TableColumn fx:id="column5" minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="156.0" text="ID"/>
            </columns>
        </TableView>
    </center>
    <bottom>
        <GridPane BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <columnConstraints>
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0"/>
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0"/>
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0"/>
            </columnConstraints>
            <rowConstraints>
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
            </rowConstraints>
            <BorderPane.margin>
                <Insets left="30.0" right="20.0"/>
            </BorderPane.margin>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="170.0" text="Добавить"
                    focusTraversable="false" onAction="#handleOpenAddForm"/>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="170.0" text="Редактировать"
                    GridPane.columnIndex="1" focusTraversable="false" onAction="#handleOpenUpdateForm"/>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="170.0" text="Удалить"
                    GridPane.columnIndex="2" focusTraversable="false" onAction="#deleteHandle"/>
        </GridPane>
    </bottom>
    <top>
        <GridPane BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <columnConstraints>
                <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="268.0" minWidth="10.0"
                                   prefWidth="259.0"/>
                <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="357.0" minWidth="10.0"
                                   prefWidth="321.0"/>
            </columnConstraints>
            <rowConstraints>
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
            </rowConstraints>
            <padding>
                <Insets left="20.0"/>
            </padding>
            <TextField prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="206.0" promptText="Введите данные для поиска . . ."
                        fx:id="txtSearch" focusTraversable="false">
                <font>
                    <Font name="Arial Italic" size="12.0"/>
                </font>
            </TextField>
        </GridPane>
    </top>
</BorderPane>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`requestFocus`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#requestFocus--) can be used on any other `Node` to remove the focus from the `TextField`. Surely you can find a `Node` where the focus does no harm...

The following example removes the focus in the `onAction` event by calling `requestFocus` on the root `Pane` of the `Scene`:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    TextField tf = new TextField();

    StackPane root = new StackPane(tf);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 200);

    tf.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        System.out.println(tf.getText());
        tf.clear();
        root.requestFocus();
    });

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```